# Create a list of exercises or any other theorem environment in LyX

Tags: lyx, theorems

I want to create a list of exercises in my LaTeX document that I am writing in the LyX editor.

If one were to write it in plain LaTeX, he would obviously write two exercise environments in a row:

```
\section{Exercises:}
\begin{exercise}
first exercise.
\end{exercise}
\begin{exercise}
second exercise.
\end{exercise}
```

I want to create something similar in LyX. But I just noticed that you cannot tell LyX where the exercise ends and where to begin a new one. Here is an example:

[image]

I succeeded creating a two exercise environments in a row, as in the code above, but only because I inserted this yellow LyX note inside a standard paragraph (look at the combo box) that has no effect on the LaTeX code.

Is there something I am missing here? Can I do it more elegantly?

This Exercise was introduced to the document by the Theorems (AMS) Module provided with the basic installation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your cursor at the end of the first exercise (that is, in the "Exercise" environment, not in the "Standard" environment, go to Insert > Separated Exercise Below, or use the keyboard shortcut Alt + P, Return.

This gives the following screenshot (note the horizontal line that indicates separation of the two exercises):

[image]